# How would you solve this (integrabitlity)?

Tags: integration

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}\\
x+1 & x\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$$
Is $f$ integrable in $\mathbb{R}$.?

Comment: Is $f$ integrable? Integrable where exactly?

Comment: in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are you asking about Riemann integrability or Lebesgue integrability?  Do you mean over $\Bbb R$ or over any bounded subset of $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

We can change the value of a function at countably many points without changing its integral, so we might as well consider $f(x)=x$ for simplicity.

A necessary condition for a function to be (Lebesgue) integrable is that $\int_{\Bbb R} f^+ dx$ is finite where $f^+(x) = \max\{0, f(x)\}$. This is not the case here. A function that is not Lebesgue integrable isn't Riemann integrable either.

We could show Riemann non-integrability directly too without changing the definition of the function $f$, for example by splitting up the integral as

$$\int_{\Bbb R} f(x)dx = \lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{n = -M}^{M} \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x)dx$$

and using partitions $\mathscr P_k$ for each integral consisting of intervals of equal width $2^{-k}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^{1} f(x)dx+\int_1^{2} f(x)dx+\cdots+\int_{n-1}^{n} f(x)dx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac {k^{2}-(k-1)^{2}} 2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (k-\frac  1 2) \to \infty$ so the function is not integrable on the real line (either in Riemann  sense or in Lebesgue sense).